# Rendering issues due to overlapping fields

Tags: bug, design

The stats of users with 10k+ reputation and many badges appear clipped in my browser (follow [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/49/copy-editor) to see an example). The following picture illustrates the problem:

[image]

the bronze badge to the left of "Werner" is cut in half.

I use Safari, but the problem doesn't seem to be a browser-specific... 
Did the site developers not anticipate that some people would reach such heights and that stats field would become this wide? How can the appearance of those stats be improved?

EDIT: I've noticed a similar problem on the [Great-Question-badge page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/22/great-question) of the main site; date & time and title overlaps:

[image]

Comment: I only have *half* a bronze badge...? Come on!

Comment: Well, technically, your name is hiding the bronze badge of whoever appears to your left :)

Comment: Can you provide the URL of the site on which this is occurring?

Comment: Related question, but not really a duplicate: [Display bug causes number of badges to be shown incorrectly](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2516)

Comment: @doncherry Have look [there](http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/49/copy-editor), for instance.

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks, feel free to edit that link into your question. The bronze badge is cut in half on FF 19 Win 7 as well.

Comment: With regard to date/title overlap: I made a feature request at meta.so: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122956/increase-the-indentation-after-date-specifications-in-badge-pages